# RequireJS optimization with baseUrl and extra folder as dependency that is a symbolic link

Tags: optimization, ember.js, requirejs, google-closure-compiler, r.js

I need to make configuration file for optimizing project with `r.js` and closure compiler.

I am using `Ember` with `requirejs`.

All major code and extra `JavaScript` libraries are in core folder that is outside someproject folder.

Inside someproject folder there is symbolic link to core folder 
If project requires some different code for some particular view or controller or whatever, it is overriden inside `someproject/app` folder.

Each project's Ember app entry point is in `someproject/app/main.js`.
Main core folder (that is outside someproject folder) does not have `main.js` file, this file is present only on project level
Require config is in each project's `index.html` file inside script tag.

Folder structure is like this

```
|- / 
|-- someproject1 
|---- app 
|------- main.js&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; --> Ember app entry point 
| 
|------- localization&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; --> Translation files 
|---------- language.js 
|---------- privacy.html 
|---------- terms.html 
| 
|------ settings &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; --> Settings for the project 
|---------- settings.js 
| 
|------ views&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; -->  For this project only some view were overriden
|---------- Application 
|---------- (Other folders with js files) 
|
|------ core&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;--> Folder with main files (symbolic link to outer folder)
|---------- app 
|---------- img 
|---------- js 
| 
|-- someproject2 
|---- app 
|---- ...and goes on... 
| 
|-- someproject3 
|---- app 
|---- ...and goes on... 
| 
|-- core 
|---- app 
|---- img 
|---- js
```

Dependencies that are specified inside main.js in each project need to be taken from core folder, that is a symbolic link on the same level as app folder where main.js file is.

#### How to create a `build.config.js` file for `r.js` with closure compiler so, that it will take start point as `someproject/app/main.js`, dependencies from `someproject/core/app` (symbolic linked folder) and exclude `JavaScript` libraries folder from optimization that is in `core/js` ?

Your help is greatly appreciated!
Remaking structure of the project will be a mess, so interested in particulary this case scenario.